# How to add Image in HTML file in Go

Tags: go

First of all, I created an HTML file using Notepad ++ with this code:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td><img src="test.jpg" border=3 height=100 width=300 /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Below is the Go language Code for this :-

```
// * /
func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        homeHandler(w, r)
    } else {
        log.Printf("rootHandler: Could not forward request for %s any further.", r.RequestURI)

        errNotFound(w, r)
    }
}
```

I want test.png should be loaded in browser but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an handler for dealing with function in an img directory, for example.

Here is one possible way to do it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func RootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Hello</h1><img src='/img/MR.png'/>")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", RootHandler) // homepage

    http.HandleFunc("/img/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mickael. I had created folder name as img and inside that keep one image named test.jpg and used above code but still its not working? Any other changes I need to do?

Comment: My code is referring to "/img/MR.png". You likely got the naming wrong.

Comment: I had used the below line 
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Hello</h1><img src='/img/test.jpg'/>")

in place of 
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Hello</h1><img src='/img/MR.png'/>")

Comment: The code is right, it work for me. Please detail what does not work if you expect more insight.

Comment: works for me, I see the image, so I do not think there is a problem in code.

Comment: When I tried to give URl localhost:8080 then Hello world is coming but not image.. when I go to url localhost:8080/img/ then image link is coming on clicking that image is loading.. Is there o way that image can load in home page itself?

Comment: Force reload the page in your browser.